# How to wait for an async function inside Parallel.Foreach

Tags: c#, async-await, parallel.foreach

I have a function that collects in a `Dictionary` values like this:

```
void Func()
{
    ....
    var dtDict = await HandleComputeBooster();
    ...
}

async private static Task
DoBooster(..., ConcurrentDict<string, DataTable> dtDict,....)
{
    DataTable dt = ...
    ...
    dtDict[symbol] = dt;
    ...
}
```

This is the function that is returning too soon:

```
async private Task<ConcurrentDictionary<string, DataTable>> 
HandleComputeBooster()
{
    var dtDict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, DataTable>();

    ....
    var chunks = listOfBoosterSymbols.ChunkBy(8);
    var pcCount = Environment.ProcessorCount;

    Parallel.ForEach(chunks, new ParallelOptions
    { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = pcCount - 2 }, async listStr =>
        {
        var symbol = listStr[0];
        await DoBooster(..., dtDict, ...);
        }
    );
    ...

    return dtDict;
}
```

the problem is that HandleComputeBooster returns before all the values in dtDict are computed. All the values eventually make into `dtDict`, but I need a way to say, don't return from HandleComputeBooster until all the chunks have been processed?

Comment: What version of dotnet are you using? 6+ has [Parallel.ForEachAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Another option is to fire them all in a normal loop, collect all the resulting tasks into a list, and then await all of them via `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)`. The parallel trigger doesn't do anything for you here, at least with your minimal example.

Comment: If `DoBooster`  loads data from a database, executing N queries can easily be slower than executing one query that loads N symbols. What does `DoBooster` do?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `async` methods in `Parallel.ForEach`. Use Parallel.ForEachAsync instead :

```
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(chunks, new (){ MaxDegreeOfParallelism = pcCount - 2 }, 
    async listStr =>
    {
        var symbol = listStr[0];
        await DoBooster(..., dtDict, ...);
    });
```

[Parallel.ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=net-7.0) doesn't have an overload that accepts a `Funct<...,Task>`. The lambda in the question's code is actually an `async void` delegate that can't be awaited:

```
async void listStr()
{
        var symbol = listStr[0];
        await DoBooster(..., dtDict, ...);
}
```

The question's code fires off as many tasks as there are items, two at a time, and never waits for them to finish.

If `DoBooster` performs IO there may not be a reason to restrict `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, as asynchronous IO doesn't block the processor.

On the other hand, if `DoBooster` is trying to "improve" data loading from a database, it will increase delays as the concurrent connections will compete for the same network and disk bandwidth and even lock each other. The best way to improve database performance is to improve the query and indexing.

For example, a single query for N symbols will be faster than N individual queries for a single symbol at a time.

This query will scan the tick table just once. Dapper makes writing the query and the `IN` clause a lot easier than dealing with ADO.NET explicitly but doesn't change the query's behavior

```
var ticks=await con.QueryAsync<Tick>("select * from StockTicks where Symbol in (@symbols)", listOfSymbols);
```

Once the ticks are loaded, they can be grouped per symbol. In this case I use `ToLookup` which creates an `ILookup<>` class similar to a multi-valued dictionary:

```
var symbolTicks=ticks.ToLookup(tick=>tick.Symbol);
```